# Regex for newline at beginning of string retrieved from textarea?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match and remove any newline at the start of a string.

```
str.replace(/^\n+/, "")
```

str is retrieved from a textarea.val and doesn't contain any newlines when I recieve it in javascript

How come this doesn't work?

Comment: i dont get it.. if you dont receive any new line chars why do you want to remove it ..

Comment: Because they exist in the textarea in the DOM and I have a data-bindnig between the str and the textarea(using angular in this instance)

Answer (score 0):

its working here

```
var str = "\n\n\n\nHOSTNAMEA, \n HOSTNAMEB,HOSTNAMEC";
var res = str.replace(/^\n+/,'');
console.log(str);
console.log(res);
```

`str` goes 4 lines down and starts

while the `res` has all new lines removed from the beginning

Comment: Hrm, my problem seems to be that when i get the value from my textarea, the browser doesn't provide the newlines in the start.

Answer (score 0):

Replace CR or LF with "".

```
str.replace(/^[\n\r]+/, "")
```

Comment: Hrm, my problem seems to be that when i get the value from my textarea, the browser doesn't provide the newlines in the start.

Comment: Do you want to remove all newlines from text `str.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, "")`